# Getting a property value from a ContentView (child view) to the ContentPage (parent)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

As a not so experienced `Xamarin` developer I am trying to retrieve a property value from a child page (`ContentView`) in my Parent page (`ContentPage`).
I can find quite some examples how to get / set the value from the parent page to the child page but not the other way around.

**Some more details:**

In my `ContentPage` I have a `CarouselView`, this `CarouselView` has a `DataTemplate` which contains a `ContentView`, this ContentView has also a CarouselView inside it with 2 layers / 2 vertical carousel items.

When the position of the CarouselView inside the ContentView (the child page), changes position to the second item, the `IndicatorView` in the parent page should be set to `invisible`.

I am not so experienced using a `BindableProperty` but I think that is the way to go. I got it setup as following for now:

**The parent page / ContentPage:**

```
<local:ExtendedCarouselView
    x:Name="carousel"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
    IndicatorView="activityIndicatorView"
    IsScrollAnimated="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityData}"
    Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <local:ExtendedCarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Style="{StaticResource CarouselWorkaround}">
                <local:PCSActivityOverviewTemplate x:Name="testy" />
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:ExtendedCarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</local:ExtendedCarouselView>

<IndicatorView
    x:Name="activityIndicatorView"
    Padding="0,0,0,30"
    IndicatorColor="{DynamicResource TranslucidBlack}"
    IsVisible="{Binding InnerCarouselViewPosition, Converter={StaticResource IndicatorVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedIndicatorColor="{DynamicResource BaseTextColor}"
    VerticalOptions="Start" />
```

**The child page / ContenView (XAML):**

```
<ContentView.Content>

    <CarouselView
        x:Name="carousel"

        ItemsSource="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource OneToManyConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
        PositionChanged="carousel_PositionChanged"> <!-- The event which should change the property 'InnerCarouselViewPosition' -->

        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector MemberName="Position">
                <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector.Items>

                    <!--  CAROUSEL'S PAGE 0  -->
                    <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem Value="0">
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <!-- Other elements... -->

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem>


                    <!--  CAROUSEL'S PAGE 1  -->
                    <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem Value="1">
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <!-- Other elements... -->

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem>

                </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector.Items>
            </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

    </CarouselView>

</ContentView.Content>
```

**The ContenView (C#/.cs):**

```
public partial class PCSActivityOverviewTemplate : ContentView
{
    public static BindableProperty CurrentChildCarouselViewLocationProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(CurrentChildCarouselViewLocationProperty),
           typeof(int),
           typeof(CarouselView),
           defaultValue: 1);

    public int CurrentChildCarouselViewLocation
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CurrentChildCarouselViewLocationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentChildCarouselViewLocationProperty, value); }
    }

    private void carousel_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CarouselView _carouselView = (CarouselView)sender;
        CurrentChildCarouselViewLocationProperty = _carouselView.Position;  
    }

    ... code omitted

}
```

When the inner carousel view position's changes then the `bindable property` should be set, this property should be used in the parent page to set the indicator view visible / invisible using a converter (position 0 = visible, position 1 = invisible).
For some, probably a quite obvious, reason the above is not working.

**The Visibility converter:**

```
public class CarouselIndicatorVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value != 1; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE***

I also tried to use a binding as the Position Property in my ViewModel, while the binding value changes, I cant access it in the Parent page nothing happens, the converter is not triggered), I removed the bindable property.

**The new Content page XAML (the parent Carousel):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    ...
    >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:CarouselIndicatorVisibilityConverter x:Key="IndicatorVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid>
            
            <Grid>
               
                <local:ExtendedCarouselView
                    x:Name="carousel"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                    IndicatorView="activityIndicatorView"
                    IsScrollAnimated="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityData}"
                    Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <local:ExtendedCarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame Style="{StaticResource CarouselWorkaround}">
                                <local:PCSActivityOverviewTemplate x:Name="testy" />
                            </Frame>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:ExtendedCarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </local:ExtendedCarouselView>

                <IndicatorView
                    x:Name="activityIndicatorView"
                    Padding="0,0,0,30"
                    IndicatorColor="{DynamicResource TranslucidBlack}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.CurrentChildCarouselViewLocation, Source={x:Reference carousel}, Converter={StaticResource IndicatorVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectedIndicatorColor="{DynamicResource BaseTextColor}"
                    VerticalOptions="Start" />


            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**XAML of the child page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    ...
    >
    
    <ContentView.Content>

        <CarouselView
            x:Name="carousel"
            IsBounceEnabled="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource OneToManyConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}"
            Position="{Binding CurrentCarouselViewLocation}"
            PositionChanged="carousel_PositionChanged"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout
                    ItemSpacing="0"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    SnapPointsAlignment="Start"
                    SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" />
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector MemberName="Position">
                    <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector.Items>

                        <!--  CAROUSEL'S PAGE 0  -->
                        <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem Value="0">
                            <DataTemplate>
                               
                               .. more elements omitted
                               
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem>

                        <!--  CAROUSEL'S PAGE 1  -->
                        <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem Value="1">
                            <DataTemplate>
                                
                                .. more elements omitted                                
                                      
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem>

                    </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector.Items>
                </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

        </CarouselView>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**The ViewModel**

```
namespace PCS2.APP.ViewModels
{
    public class ActivityOverviewViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private List<ActivityLocation> activityData;
        private readonly IRoutingService _routingService;
        private double _screenOpacity;
        private bool _showLoadingAnimation;
        private int? _clientId;
        private int _position;
        private int _innerCarouselPosition;

        // Position of the Parent page CarouselView
        public int Position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _position, value); }
        }

        // Data source for the child data
        public List<ActivityLocation> ActivityData
        {
            get { return activityData; }
            set { SetProperty(ref activityData, value); }
        }

    
        public double ScreenOpacity
        {
            get { return _screenOpacity; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _screenOpacity, value); }
        }

        public bool ShowLoadingAnimation
        {
            get { return _showLoadingAnimation; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _showLoadingAnimation, value); }
        }

        public ActivityOverviewViewModel(int? clientId = null, IRoutingService routingService = null)
            : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _routingService = routingService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IRoutingService>();
            LoadData();
        }

        private async void LoadData()
        {
            try
            {
                ShowLoadingAnimation = true;
                ScreenOpacity = 0.1;

                // Getting the data
                var _activitiesData = await App.Database.GetActivityDataAsync(_clientId, DateTime.UtcNow);
                ActivityData = _activitiesData;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                ShowLoadingAnimation = false;
                ScreenOpacity = 1.0;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good approach to have a CarouselView with a DataTemplate that contains another CarouselView. `ContentPage->CarouselView.DataTemplate->ContentView->CarouselView`

Comment: The `IndicatorVisibilityConverter` is never triggered. Added the converter in the main post.

Comment: Yep, like so: `<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:CarouselIndicatorVisibilityConverter x:Key="IndicatorVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>` but it looks like the bindableproperty is just not 'bubbled' back to the Parent page from the child page.

Comment: @Cfun Sadly this generates the error `Can not find the object referenced by 'testy'`

Comment: @Nicolas How do you get this error? We need more details.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT also added my ViewModel (updated the main post), don't know what more details I can give you now, practically the entire page and it's contents are posted.. Also tried a few other ways, like adding the child carousel position as a ViewModel Binding and use that binding back in the Parent page, this also is not working. It has to be some binding issue I suppose..

Comment: Have you used the same viewmodel for the parent and child page?